# All radio group listeners called on click of any one radio button

Tags: android, oncheckedchanged, android-radiogroup

```
    RadioGroup r1 = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.first);
    r1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
        {
            Utilities.createDebugToastMsg(rootView.getContext(), "clicked on R1");
        }
    });

    RadioGroup r2 = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.second);
    r2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            Utilities.createDebugToastMsg(rootView.getContext(), "clicked on R2");
        }
    });
}
```

I have TWO separate radio groups, consisting of THREE radio buttons each. Now which ever radio button I click, both the listeners are called and I get both the toast messages.
Please help and point out if there is anything I have missed or messed up. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Can you post the xml too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a switch case in your code. Like below:

```
     switch (view.getId()) {

                case R.id.first:
                    your code here for what to do when it is clicked/checked
                    break;          
                    case R.id.second:
                    your code here for what to do when it is clicked/checked
                    break; 
}
```

As you don't have any switch case in your code, both the functions are executing. So, do the above implementation which will help you to do what you require...